# Composition of functions has to be $C^{1}$ to conclude concavity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis

Let $f:(0, \infty)\to (0, \infty)$ be a function defined by $$f(x)=f_{1}(x),\qquad 0<x<x_{0}$$ and $$f(x)=f_{2}(x), \qquad x\geq x_{0},$$ where $f_{1}:(0, x_{0}]\to (0, \infty)$ is smooth and satisfies $f_{1}''(x)<0$ on $(0, x_{0}]$ and $f_{2}:(0, \infty)\to (0, \infty)$ is smooth and satisfies $f_{2}''(x)<0$ on $(0, \infty)$. Suppose also that $f$ is continuous in $x_{0}$, that is $f_{1}(x_{0})=f_{2}(x_{0})$.

My question: Does $f$ have to be $C^{1}$ in $x_{0}$, that is $f'_{1}(x_{0})=f'_{2}(x_{0})$, to conclude that $f$ is concave in $(0, \infty)$?

Edit: My actual question is: Is it sufficient to show that $f$ is $C^{1}$ to obtain concavity and this answered below.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes. Just visually suppose, that you have $\sqrt{x}$ for $f_{1}(x)$, and construct $f_{2}$, in such a way, as if to copy the first function starting at the point $(x_{0}, f_{1}(x_{0}))$. (Visually it looks like concave function adjusted to another concave function, like one hill, continued by another hill, (a little bit more steeper, than previous one).).

Comment: @kolobokish That should be an answer. I like that explanation a lot

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Thank you. Next time.))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general it will not be concave without the $C^1$ hypothesis. Consider something that looks like the upper part of heart, say $f(x)=\vert \cos(x)\vert$ around $x_0=\pi/2$. Then this is clearly not concave (draw a picture and then show it analytically).

**Added:** As correctly pointed out in the comments below by @AndrewD.Hwang, actually the real question is slightly different. It is not necessary for $f$ to be $C^1$ for $f$ to be concave. Consider
$$ f(x)= 1 - e^{-\vert x-x_0\vert}.$$

**Added even later:** If we know that $f$ is $C^1$, then we are in good shape. By the condition on the second derivative, we know that $f'$ is decreasing on both $(0,x_0]$ and $[x_0, \infty)$ and by the continuity of $f'$ we obtain, that $f'$ is actually decreasing on all of $(0,\infty)$ and hence concave.

Comment: Not sure I understand: If $0 < a < 1$ and
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  x = f_{1}(x) & 0 < x < 1 = x_{0}, \\
  ax + (1 - a) = f_{2}(x) & 1 \leq x,
\end{cases}
$$
doesn't $f$ satisfy OP's constraints (except strict concavity, which is easily fixed) yet is not $C^{1}$?

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang I am sorry, I am not sure what you mean. I am just giving a counterexample to the concavity without the $C^1$ condition. Are you saying that I missed a condition?

Comment: As I read it, OP wants to know "If $f$ is obtained by patching functions with negative second derivative, and if $f$ is concave, must $f$ be $C^{1}$?" The answer is "no": It is possible for $f$ to be concave yet not $C^1$. So while you're correct that "In general [$f$] will not be concave without the $C^1$ hypothesis," that's not what I understand OP to be asking.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thank you very much, you are indeed correct. I should have read the question more carefully.

Comment: Maybe how the question is stated is not how I meant it. It is meant that, if I know that f is obtained by patching functions with negative second derivative and I want to show that f is concave, is it enough to show that f is C1?

Comment: But that is answered in the first part of your answer.

Comment: @Shaq155 If your function is $C^1$, then your function is concave. That is because $f'$ is decreasing on both $(0,x_0]$ and $[x_0,\infty)$. If $f$ is $C^1$, then we conclude that $f'$ is decreasing on all of $(0,\infty)$ and hence concave.